# JSONArray Parsing in Android

Tags: java, android, json

I have a JSON Array with a strong single object inside it.

```
[{
  "Date": "2016-02-26 00:54:35",
  "Temp": "24.00"
}]
```

I have been trying to parse it to an Android application via text view, however, the `TextView` field displays as blank when the application is ran. I've tried many different tutorials and neither has worked. My current code on the parsing is below. I have a separate class for the HTTP connections.

```
  protected void onPostExectue(String stream) {
        TextView Temp1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTemp);

        Temp1.setText(stream);


        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                //data arrives as JSON array

                JSONArray reader = new JSONArray(stream);

                int readerLength = reader.length();
                if(readerLength > 0)
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < readerLength; i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject item = reader.getJSONObject(i);
                        String d = item.getString("Date");

                    }
                }
```

I attempted to declare the `JSONArray` first and then read the object from within.

Editing due to comment below to show the stream:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String stream = null;
        String urlString = strings[0];

        HTTPDataHandler hh = new HTTPDataHandler();
        stream = hh.GetHTTPData(urlString);

        // Return the data from specified url
        return stream;
    }
```

Comment: is the JSON in this format: `[ {Date : something}, {Date : foo} ]`?

Comment: @giannisf sorry, edited the question to include JSON

Comment: put the `.setText` after parsing `JSON`.

Comment: @giannisf same result, blank text view when I run the application

Comment: Did you check that `stream` is not empty and is valid `JSON` string?

Comment: @giannisf I've edited the post to show the stream, I hope I've set it correctly to use the HTTP class and call the url? But does this make it an invalid JSON string?

Comment: Have you stepped through with a debugger?  That might show you what's going wrong.